# JavaFX Toggle Group Change

Tags: events, javafx

i have a lot of Toggle Buttons! They are all in one toggle group, now i want to add a change listener! If there is one event one a toggle button in this group i want to have a event on the other buttons too!

How can i check that?

I made something like this, but it doesn't work very well:

```
triangleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>()
{
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> arg0, Toggle arg1, Toggle arg2)
    {
        if (btnTriangle.getRotate() != iRotateCoord1)
        {
            closeTriangle();
        }
    }
});
```

So the triangleGroup represents my ToggleGroup! There i add a ChangeListener.... If there ia a Event, the current btnTriangle ( ToggleButton ) will close if it has not the rotate value like iRotate...

How can I get the Event when ever there is a Event on this Button Group or when ever there is a change...

Or is there a possibility to get all of the buttons that are in the Group?

Comment: What exactly is `btnTriangle` in your code? What exactly is `iRotateCoord1`? How does `closeTriangle()` relate to all that?

Comment: @TomasMikula btnTiangle is a Toggle Button! iRotateCoord is a virtual Value, thats not really important! closeTriangle should switch the btnTriangle - Rotation about 90 degrees...

Comment: I mean which button? You say you have a lot of them. If it is the one that is currently selected, then it is the `arg2` argument of your listener. If it is the one selected previously, then it is the `arg1` argument of your listener. You should use the listener arguments if possible, it makes for cleaner code. Maybe this is all you are asking for - handle the currently selected button?

Comment: Also, you should use `equals` to compare objects for equality, since in Java `==`/`!=` compares object references. That means, for example, that `new Integer(5) == new Integer(5)` is false. Also, I would suggest refactoring your `closeTriangle` method so that it takes the triangle to rotate as an argument, i.e. `closeTriangle(Toggle btnTriangle)`.